# What werewolf hunter uses this equipment (crossbow and hat)?

Tags: weapon, werewolf, object-identification

Science Fiction Stack Exchange and some other Stack Exchange sites are currently running a game called the "Winter bash" where users can earn "hats", overlay images they can add to their user avatar.  One of these awards is called "Werewolf Hunter", and is awarded for gaining a silver badge within the holiday period.  The image for this hat depics a hat and what looks sort of like a crossbow (see image below).

What does this image really represent, and how is it connected to werewolf hunting?  Is this sort of hat and weapon worn by a particular famous werewolf hunter in some piece of fantasy fiction?

[image: Werewolf hunting hat]

Yes, I am deliberately asking this on the main site of SciFi SE (not on meta), because I'd like to know about the pop culture references this is trying to evoke.  I could ask the same thing here if some website unrelated to SE gave such an award.  Werewolf hunters probably mostly occur in fantasy fiction, which is why this is the site I'm asking on.

Comment: For another non-meta question on what the winter hats represent, see http://english.stackexchange.com/q/215399/32815

Comment: Shouldn't this be a meta question?

Comment: @Robert: no. It's a question about werewolf hunters, as they are depicted in fantasy fiction.  But wait, I'll retitle it to make that clearer.

Comment: Yeah, the title would have gotten the question closed as off topic.  I guess I could have edited it.  Now the question makes sense.

Comment: Oh. That's a hand with a crossbow. I assumed it was a hat with an attached minigun...

Comment: @SeanDuggan: it might be a minigun for all I know. Don't take "crossbow" as definitive.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This seems to be most closely based on Gabriel Van Helsing from the 2004 movie *[Van Helsing](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0338526/)* who was a hunter who was also a werewolf (he hunted Vampires and other monsters generally, tho)

[image]

Comment: Wasn't Van Helsing a human who became infected by a werewolf during the movie? If I recall, he was later cured before the infection was incurable.

Comment: He was an angel who hunted a vampire, shot a werewolf, became a werewolf, and killed Dracula.